# Push md file from local git repo to remote github repo

Tags: git, github, push

I am quite new to git and I am trying to perform the seemingly simple operation of pushing one single file from my local repo to github...

Whenever I enter `git push` the following is the result

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

and now, whenever actually entering `git push --set-upstream origin master` I get the following error

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
To https://github.com/user/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Luca

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first). 

So fetch first as indicated, then maybe merge, then push.

Comment: Try `git pull origin master`

Comment: Thank you both - I have performed  'git fetch' , but when trying to merge this is the result _fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge._ also when trying to 'git pull origin master' I get following error _! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those who provided me with their input.

```
git push origin master
```

actually resolved the issue, as it would not let me merge remote with current branch.
now all the local files have been replicated in the remote repo.